# What does this Python 3 function do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anybody help me to find out how this function works?

```
def get_matched_birthdays(birthdays):
    if len(birthdays) == len(set(birthdays)):
        return None
    for a, birthdayA in enumerate(birthdays):
        for b, birthdayB in enumerate(birthdays[a+1:]):
            if birthdayA == birthdayB:
                return birthdayA
```

Here is birthdays: https://ghostbin.com/paste/4tM0V

I am understanding the first two lines but what's happening inside those two for loops?

Comment: What precisely do you not understand? Have you read the [docs on `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), for example?

Comment: Have you considered using some `print` statements to see what is happening?

Comment: It's a weird or at least sub-optimal way to find duplicates elements in a list.

Comment: Not really duplicates, just the first instance of the same date twice in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function basically loops through the "birthdays" list and checks to see if an element appears further down the list and returns the value every time it sees it down the line.

First for loop just loops through the "birthdays" list and gives each element an index which is stored in variable "a".

```
for a, birthdayA in enumerate(birthdays):
```

The second loop takes a subset of "birthdays" list and loops through it. The subset starts at the index "a+1" and ends at the end of the "birthdays" list.

```
    for b, birthdayB in enumerate(birthdays[a+1:]):
```

The function then returns the values where the items in "birthdays" list comes up again in the list.

```
        if birthdayA == birthdayB:
            return birthdayA
```

If you want a more efficient way of checking for dupes and returning the index of dupes perhaps use something like this:

```
>>> dupes_lst = []
>>> unique_set = set()
>>> lst = [1,2,3,1,1,4,2]
>>> for i, item in enumerate(lst):
...     if item in unique_set:
...             dupes_lst.append(i)
...     else:
...             unique_set.add(item)
```

More on enumerate at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html :

```
seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
```